# Две функции на одной кнопке

Tags: php, javascript

На кнопке весит две функции onlick, но по какой-то причине выскакивает ошибка Unexpected end of input

Вот кнопка:

```
<div class="btn btn-v-1" style="margin-top:30px" type="text" onclick="SaveCountry();throw_message("Upload!")">Upload</div>
```

Вот функции:

```
<script>
    function throw_message(str) {
        $('#error_message').html(str);
        $("#error_box").fadeIn(500).delay(3000).fadeOut(500);
    }
</script>   


        <script>
function SaveCountry(){
        var country = document.getElementById('country').value;
    $.ajax({
            url: 'country.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {country:country},
            success: function(res){
                $('.alert').css('background',res.color)
                Alert_Opoveshenie(res.message);
            },
            error: function(){
                $('.alert').css('background','red')
                Alert_Opoveshenie('Error!');
            }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Кавычки внутри других кавычек поломали Ваш html:

```js
function SaveCountry() {
  console.log("SaveCountry");
}

function throw_message(aMessage) {
  throw aMessage;
}
```

```css
.btn {
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn btn-v-1" style="margin-top:30px" type="text" 
  onclick="SaveCountry();throw_message('Upload!')">Upload</div>
```